# Performing a Depth first search and breadth first search in Boost

Tags: c++, boost, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, boost-graph

I am pretty much new to both Boost library and c++ language.

I have created a graph using Boost and added vertex and edges and output the graph in graphviz.

Now I would like to perform a breadth first and depth first search from a vertex to all the other vertex in the graph.

The result should should be the shortest path from start vertex to other vertex in the graph.

How can I accomplish this in Boost? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance.

I have also added my source code for your reference.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/pending/indirect_cmp.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

int main()
{
            using namespace std;
            using namespace boost;


        // Property types
            typedef property<vertex_name_t, std::string,
            property<vertex_index2_t, int> > VertexProperties;

        // Graph type
            typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS,
            VertexProperties> Graph;

        // Graph instance
            Graph g;

        // Property accessors
            property_map<Graph, vertex_name_t>::type
            profinet_name = get(vertex_name, g);
            property_map<Graph, vertex_index2_t>::type
            profinet_index2 = get(vertex_index2, g);

        // Create the vertices
            typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
            Vertex u1;
            u1 = add_vertex(g);
            profinet_name[u1] = "Profinet 1";
            profinet_index2[u1] = 1;

            Vertex u2;
            u2 = add_vertex(g);
            profinet_name[u2] = "Profinet 2";
            profinet_index2[u2] = 2;

            Vertex u3;
            u3 = add_vertex(g);
            profinet_name[u3] = "Profinet 3";
            profinet_index2[u3] = 3;

            Vertex u4;
            u4 = add_vertex(g);
            profinet_name[u4] = "Profinet 4";
            profinet_index2[u4] = 4;

            Vertex u5;
            u5 = add_vertex(g);
            profinet_name[u5] = "Profinet 5";
            profinet_index2[u5] = 5;

            Vertex u6;
            u6 = add_vertex(g);
            profinet_name[u6] = "Profinet 6";
            profinet_index2[u6] = 6;


        // Create the edges
            typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
            Edge e1;
            e1 = (add_edge(u1, u2, g)).first;

            Edge e2;
            e2 = add_edge(u1, u4, g).first;

            Edge e3;
            e3 = (add_edge(u1, u6, g)).first;

            Edge e4;
            e4 = (add_edge(u2, u3, g)).first;

            Edge e5;
            e5 = (add_edge(u2, u4, g)).first;

            Edge e6;
            e6 = (add_edge(u2, u5, g)).first;

            Edge e7;
            e7 = (add_edge(u3, u6, g)).first;

            Edge e8;
            e8 = (add_edge(u6, u5, g)).first;

            Edge e9;
            e9 = (add_edge(u5, u4, g)).first;


            write_graphviz(cout, g);

            return 0;


}
```

Comment: Does the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html) not describe it well enough?

Comment: @jogojapan It isn't that clear. I tried reading the document but, the example code has no comment and it's difficult to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform a shortest path from a to b, you should rather use the Dijkstra algorithm.

A BFS is theoreticaly better if all your edges have a cost of 1, but in boost::graph it requires some effort (it is just an empty shell and you need to implement your own visitors in order to store the distance from the origins).

However, in order to use the dijkstra, you need to add Edge properties with weights on the edges and use it in the algorithm.

In the following example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example.cpp you can unwind the shortest path from s to t by looking at the predecessors map : p[t] is the node before t in the shortest path.

I hope this is enough :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But what exactly i want here is, to find the vertices that are reachable from a given vertex and would like to display the path. I would also like to perform Dijkstra algorithm but initially, I wanted to start with DFS and BFS.

Comment: So, what is missing? With Dijkstra, all the reachable nodes u are those where p[u] != u. Using DFS and BFS in boost requires some extra work as you need to implement your own visitor : look at the examples http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/example/bfs-example.cpp

Comment: Thanks for relpying, but how can i implement my own visitors?? Is there an example that shows me how to do it?

Comment: In the url I gave in the previous response…